# What are differences between Ext.create() and Ext.define() in SenCha Touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have been learning SenCha Touch for awhile and still feel confused when trying to create a store.

In the SenCha Documentation, it says to use Ext.create() [Example](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/stores)
I tried and it simply doesn't work.

For the rest of others, I always see people use Ext.define() to create a store and it works.

Now, my question is:
what are the differences between them and when/how to use either one of them in a right way?

Some demo code is highly appreciated

Thanks a lot my friends.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`define` is for declaring a class.

```
Ext.define('Foo', {
    extend: 'Bar'
});

// Similar to:
public class Foo : Bar {
}
```

`create` is for creating an instance:

```
var o = Ext.create('Foo'); // Can also have var o = new Foo();

// Similar to:
Foo o = new Foo();
```

Answer (score 5):

Ext.create
 - to create an instance of a pre-defined class.
 - the class was defined using Ext.define
 - used to define the data and behavior of a component. which will be used later.

Ext.define
 - to define your own class definition
 - reusable component.
 - instances can be created using Ext.create API.