# extjs4 grid simple example but an error: 'items' of undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have been practicing to make a really simple grid example on JSFiddle, I've stuck in this problem.

I have 1 model, 1 store, and 1 grid object. I think I put everything properly into appropriate spaces, but all I got from the result was 'Cannot read property "items" of undefined', can anyone please explain why this happens to me, please?

```js
var model = Ext.create('Ext.data.Model', {
  fields: [
    {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
    {name: 'value', type: 'float'}
  ]
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
  model: model,
  data: [
    {name: 'a', value: 1.2},
    {name: 'b', value: 2.3},
    {name: 'c', value: 3.4},
    {name: 'd', value: 4.5},
  ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
  width: 500,
  height: 500,
  store: store,
  columns: [
    {text: 'header', dataIndex: 'name'},
    {text: 'header2', dataIndex: 'value'}
  ],
  renderTo: Ext.getBody()
})
```

Comment: You're supposed to be defining the model, not creating.

Comment: true,something like this Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'name', 'email'],})

Comment: Can you guys tell me why? As you two have said, it's right to declare it by defining, not creating, but I don't get why..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you are using [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) then you need to include ExtJS all required libraries like

1. [ext-all-debug.js](https://extjs.cachefly.net/ext/gpl/5.1.0/build/ext-all-debug.js) as per depend on your requirement you can change version of ExtJS library.
2. [ext-theme-neptune](https://extjs.cachefly.net/ext/gpl/5.1.0/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/ext-theme-neptune.js) only for theme what you want to use you can change.
3. [ext-theme-neptune-all-debug](https://extjs.cachefly.net/ext/gpl/5.1.0/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/resources/ext-theme-neptune-all-debug.css) only for theme what you want to use you can change.

Here in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/narendrajadhav105/r1rrqus5) I have created an demo you check here how it is working. Hope this will help you.

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'simpsonsStore',
    fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data:{'items':[
        { 'name': 'Lisa',  "email":"lisa@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-111-1224"  },
        { 'name': 'Bart',  "email":"bart@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1234" },
        { 'name': 'Homer', "email":"homer@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1244"  },
        { 'name': 'Marge', "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1254"  }
    ]},
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'items'
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name' },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: '100%',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

You can also check here working [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27ob).

Answer (score 0):

'Create' creates an instance of the parent element.Hence need to define model,before creating instances of it.

```
Ext.define('occupationModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        {name: 'code', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'occup', type: 'string'}
    ]
});

Ext.create('occupationModel', {
    code : 1,
    occup : 'foo'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for your problem is to change your model with below code.

```html
Ext.define('model', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: [
                        {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
                        {name: 'value', type: 'float'}
                    ]
                });
```

Also, click on link to know more about, [Differences between Ext.create() and Ext.define()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23003450/what-are-differences-between-ext-create-and-ext-define-in-sencha-touch)