# extjs difference between define and create

Tags: extjs6

In the Ext JS 6.7.0 documentation all the examples show a Ext.data.Store being created using Ext.create.  In every tutorial I've seen the data stores are always created using Ext.define.  What is the difference?  The store I've created using Ext.define cannot be referenced using the storeId, and I'm wondering if it's because I used Ext.define instead of Ext.create.

```
`var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('idofstore');`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are differences between Ext.create() and Ext.define() in SenCha Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23003450/what-are-differences-between-ext-create-and-ext-define-in-sencha-touch)

Comment: Yes, kind of a duplicate. The linked question is for Sencha Touch. The OP is asking about Ext JS 6.7.0. Sencha Touch was replaced by the two toolkit framework. Modern toolkit for mobile/responsive, classic toolkit for desktop browser. Might be good to leave the question considering the framework changed and Touch is no longer used.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/modern/Ext.html#method-define)

> Ext.define - Defines a class or override
>   Ext.create - Instantiate a class by either full name, alias or alternate name

If you define something it will need to be instantiated in order to access it using the id. You used define, so you cannot lookup your store until it is instantiated.